# Android Studio SQLiteOpenHelper "DATABSE has no column named NAME"

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, android-studio

I know this has been asked allot but i have checked all the other Questions and none Fixed my problem.

This is the Exception:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Traust_Du_Dich_App has no column named name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Loras gender=Male birthday=21
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Traust_Du_Dich_App has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Traust_Du_Dich_App(name,gender,birthday) VALUES (?,?,?)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
   at com.lukas.saufapp.MyDbHandler.addProduct(MyDbHandler.java:57)
   at com.lukas.saufapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:232)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is the HelperClass:

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quadstudios_de";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Traust_Du_Dich_App";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String COLUMN_BDAY = "birthday";

    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT," + COLUMN_BDAY + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void AddUser(User user) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, user.Name);
        values.put(COLUMN_GENDER, user.Gender);
        values.put(COLUMN_BDAY, user.Birthday);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Here I call It:

```
Btn_FaceBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyDbHandler handler = new MyDbHandler(MainActivity.this, null, null, 1);
        User user = new User("Thomas", "Male", "21");
        handler.AddUser(user);
}
```

Comment: Did you added column name recently? Maybe, you need to update the DB version in order to add the column (try to change DATABASE_VERSION to 3).

Comment: No I added it straight when i created the Table

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can think of is not updating your version number. Whenever you modify the columns in the database, you have to update the version number as well.

Instead of this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Try this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
```

Comment: That didnt help is it correct that I named DATABSE_NAME and TABLE like this when the Database looks like this ? http://quadstudios.de/Unbenannt.PNG

Comment: And Where does the Code know where to push the Insert only by its name?

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the app from the device where you are testing it. This will delete the database. Now reinstall the app so it will recreate the database from the beginning.